# Using PHP to add Microdata to body with IF and ELSE

Tags: php, joomla, microdata

I suspect this is an easy to fix problem but PHP is one of many weaknesses I have. Basically I'm using Joomla CMS and I want to use Microdata (using Schema.org) on both product pages and business pages. So I've made an attempt to use `$menuID`  and using `IF` and `ELSE` statments. I want to select 5 pages or so which should echo `http://schema.org/Product` if page ID matches else echo `http://schema.org/LocalBusiness`.

The problem is that `ELSE` is being ignored and `http://schema.org/Product` is being used every page.

Here is the code I've made:

```
<body class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?>" itemscope
    itemtype="<?php $menuID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id;
            if($menuID == '115' | '116' | '117' | '118' | '119') {
                echo'http://schema.org/Product';
            } else {
                echo'http://schema.org/LocalBusiness';}
                ?>
            ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little error in your if-else statement. :)

Solution 1:

```
if($menuID == '115' || $menuID == '116' || $menuID == '117' || $menuID == '118' || $menuID == '119'){ ... } else { ... }
```

Soltion 2:

```
$pageIDs = array('115', '116', '117', '118', '119');
if (in_array($menuID, $pageIDs){ ... } else { ... }
```